Why does my redirected page ignore css styling and images
My .htaccess file that redirects users to a maintenance page but the page is displayed without any of my css styling
My .htaccess file looks like this.
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect to maintenance page unless query parameter supplied
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^allowLogin=true$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/maintenance.php [R,L]

When the maintenance page is displayed via the .htaccess redirect, it looks like the image below. Notice the empty image and the lack of background color.
With .htaccess redirect
Without the .htaccess file, the page looks like the image below. Notice that the image is now correctly displayed and there is a colored background.
Without .htaccess redirect
The image is loaded by reference to the file containing it.
<img src="assets/img/current-logo.png" width="250px"></a>
The css background command is in a file loaded in the <head> tag
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
Here is a screenshot of the network tab in my Chrome browser debug tools showing all the calls and responses for the index and maintenance pages.  They look OK to me but I'm not familiar enough with that tool to know if there are any problematic issues in it.
Chrome debug network screenshot here
For comparison, the Chrome network axreensghot I remove the .htaccess file is here
I am also seeing errors in the Chrome Console as shown  here These errors are in third party tools and do not occur when I remove the .htaccess file.
I should also say this problem is not limited to the maintenance.php file. When I point my browser to any other file in my domain file and include the allowLogin query parameter,they are displayed with the same problems, missing background color and empty images.
Any help much appreciated

You're using relative URL's in the links to the CSS and image file. That can be problematic when the root changes. Why not try /assets/ instead of assets/? See: Absolute vs relative URLs

What's unclear in the comment I left in the staging ground? Requests to images and styles are ALSO get redirected by this rule

@YourCommonSense Please remember that comments in the staging ground should never try to answer the question...

@Kiko Soaftware Thganks for the link, I tried your suggestion but unfortunatelt it didn't cure the problem

@YOur Common Sense I'm sorry but I didn't understand your comment in staging.  The network listing shows 2 entries for current-logo.png, one resulted in a status of 302 whihc I think indicates a temporary redirect and the other resulted in a status of 200 (success) The network listing after I removed the htaccess file (so no redirects) shows just thw status 200 for current-logo.png.  That all seems OK to me but if it isn;t please let me know what I should expect to see.

You have two conditions for a rewrite in your .htaccess: 1. Skip the rewrite when the query string contains allowLogin=true. 2. Skip the rewrite when the URL contains /maintenance.php. Both seem to be intended to prevent endless recursion. Nothing wrong with that. But this means that everything else, including CSS and images, will be rewritten, that means, redirected to maintenance.php. Why not add more conditions to also skip the rewrite when the URL contains the CSS or image file? Or, alternatively use RewriteRule (.php) instead of RewriteRule (.*).

All your requests for stylesheets are being redirected to maintenance.php as well. You'll need to make more exceptions for those types of files, or limit your redirects to only .php files.

@PeterHaworth I agree that this answer is very short, but it basically says the same as in my comment above. When you know what it means it is understandable, but when not it can be difficult.

@Peter The browser requests style.css from your server. The server responds with a redirect to maintenance.php, because of your rewrite rule. The browser again requests the URL maintenance.php as instructed, expecting to find a stylesheet there. Which of course it doesn't. Which is where those error messages in the log come from. Clear now?

@deceze Thanks for the post but the light bulb still isn't going on, sorry.  Looking at what I posted again, it may not be clear that the maintenance.php file is in the same domain as the redirected file and the maintenance.php file also includes the exact same  tag to the styles.css file as the redirected file (index.php).
I appreciate your explanation and I wish I understood what is going on.  Is there something I can do in either the htaccess file or the maintenance.php file to solve these issues?

@Peter I’m not sure what exactly you’re missing either. Are you thinking in terms of HTTP requests? The browser is making HTTP requests to your server and works with whatever it responds with. Try playing around with bare HTTP clients like Postman or curl to see this at a fundamental level. Or at least click around the browser network inspector more and dig into the details of each request more (you can click on them!). Your server is responding with the same thing for all your requests: a redirect to the maintenance.php file. It just doesn’t serve the CSS files or images due to that.

OK, light bulb came on thanks. Am I right in thinking that if I can somehow exclude the styles.css and the current-logo.png file from being redirected in the htaccess file, that would fix the problem, assuming that’s possible?

I added RewriteCond rules to the htaccess file to exclude the styles and current-logo files from the redirect, all works fine now.  Thanks to all for helping me figuring this out.
